# How do I input text into a Python script on a remote server?

Tags: python, email

I have a python script saved on an Amazon EC2 instance that sends an email:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

me = "filleremail@gmail.com"
my_password = r"password"
you = "receiver@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Alert"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

#TODO: How do I get email text from user
part2 = MIMEText(email_text)

msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via gmail's regular server, over SSL - passwords are being sent, afterall
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
# uncomment if interested in the actual smtp conversation
# s.set_debuglevel(1)
# do the smtp auth; sends ehlo if it hasn't been sent already
s.login(me, my_password)

s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I want to submit text from a mobile app using a URL to fill the email_text variable. I have some experience with POST and GET requests but not on connecting them through Python. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Good keywords to search for: "python rest api"

Comment: There are a few frameworks that allow you to build these kind of services in python. Consider having a look at fastAPI, flask, and if you have a heavier application - Django.

Comment: @Roy2012 Thank you for the feedback. I'm looking into using Flask.